# Getting Proxy Authentication Erorr on Azure CLI

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cli

I am new to all the this Azure/Kubernetes/Docker thing. So I was trying to run a command on Azure CLI.

```
az aks install-cli
```

I downloads the `kubectl` just fine. But when downloading the kubelogin from github I get an error.

```
Downloading client to "C:\Users\sm187t\.azure-kubectl\kubectl.exe" from "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.23.4/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe"
Please add "C:\Users\sm187t\.azure-kubectl" to your search PATH so the `kubectl.exe` can be found. 2 options:
    1. Run "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\sm187t\.azure-kubectl" or "$env:path += 'C:\Users\sm187t\.azure-kubectl'" for PowerShell. This is good for the current command session.
    2. Update system PATH environment variable by following "Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables", and re-open the command window. You only need to do it once
Downloading client to "C:\Users\sm187t\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpk55o6j2v\kubelogin.zip" from "https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin/releases/download/v0.0.11/kubelogin.zip"
**Connection error while attempting to download client (<urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required>)**
```

But being new, I am not what to look for. I am running it on Windows Powershell.

I can understand that it might be something to do with my proxy. But I am not sure where to put in the username/password for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure how you are trying to download the **kubelogin** from GITHUB using PowerShell.

But you can download the **kubelogin** directly in your local by pasting the below url in your web browser and hitting enter.

```
https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin/releases/download/v0.0.11/kubelogin.zip
```

[image]

Make you have git install for your window if not you can refer this [Document](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) for the same.
Once install you can check the version for conformation of installation.

[image]